# How to convert a ofxcvGrayscaleImage to Mat?

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, openframeworks

I'm making an ios app that uses both openframeworks and opencv. I'm currently trying to use this function:

void HoughCircles(InputArray image, OutputArray circles, int method, double dp, double minDist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int minRadius=0, int maxRadius=0 ), where:

- src_gray: Input image (grayscale), 8-bit, single-channel, grayscale
  input image.
- circles: A vector that stores sets of 3 values: x_{c},
  y_{c}, r for each detected circle.
- CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT: Define the
  detection method. Currently this is the only one available in OpenCV
- dp = 1: The inverse ratio of resolution
- min_dist = src_gray.rows/8:
  Minimum distance between detected centers
- param_1 = 200: Upper
  threshold for the internal Canny edge detector
- param_2 = 100*:
  Threshold for center detection.
- min_radius = 0: Minimum radio to be
  detected. If unknown, put zero as default.
- max_radius = 0: Maximum
  radius to be detected. If unknown, put zero as default

I'm having trouble changing the format of the image to a pixel array that the function will accept. grayImage is of type ofxCvGrayscaleImage

This is the code I currently have

```
//prepare image
grayImage.blurGaussian();

//detect circles in image
ofPixels pixels;
pixels = grayImage.getPixels();
cv::Mat imageMat(grayImage.width, grayImage.height, CV_8UC3);
for(int i = 0; i < pixels.size(); i++){
    imageMat.push_back(pixels[i]);
    }
cv::HoughCircles(imageMat, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, grayImage.height/8, 200, 100, 5, 30);
```

The program builds fine, but when I run that page, it crashes and returns the following error:
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1) in push_back, file ../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 690
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: ../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:690: error: (-215) DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1 in function push_back

Any suggestions what to do with the ofxCvGrayscaleImage?

**UPDATE: the answer was just
cv::Mat imgMat = grayImage.getCvImage()**

Comment: `imageMat.push_back`doesn't make any sense ;)

Comment: so then what should I do to generate the proper input array